# Why do we unavoidably (or not) use Riemann integral to define Itô integral?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itô_calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus)

Define
$$\int_0^tH_tdB_t\equiv \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nH_{t_i}(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}})$$

But I'm wondering **why not defining this using Lebesgue Integral**?

It looks more consistent, meaning we can somehow 'obsolete' Riemann integral after knowing Lebesgue Integral. Moreover, we can integrate processes that are hard to integrate. Isn't this good?

**Quote from wikipedia:** 
Suppose that $B$ is a Wiener process (Brownian motion) and that $H$ is a right-continuous (cadlag), adapted and locally bounded process. If 
$\{π_n\}$ is a sequence of partitions of $[0, t]$ with mesh going to zero, then the Itô integral of H with respect to B up to time t is a random variable. It can be shown that this limit converges in probability...

Or maybe because the above condition that the limit converge is strong enough in most situations?

Comment: How would you define this in terms of Lebesgue-integrals? The Brownian motion has almost surely unbounded variation, so you can't write it as the difference of two monotone functions.

Comment: But this is clearly a Riemann sum, when the Riemann sum converges then the function is Riemann integrable and hence Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: This is not a Riemann-sum, but a Riemann-Stieltjes sum. Your statement does not hold in this case.

Comment: @Dominik so Riemann-Stieljes Integral can apply to more functions than Lebesgue?

Comment: This is not the problem. The problem is how you would define the measure with respect to which you want to integrate in the sense of Lebesgue. This will in general only make sense for functions of bounded variation.

Comment: @Dominik I think he means Lebesgue Stieljes Integral?

Comment: @monotonic Exactly this construction does not work because of the unbounded variation of the Brownian motion.

Answer (score 21):

First of all, note that the limit

$$\int_0^t H(s) \, dB_s = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n H_{t_i} (B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}}) \tag{1}$$

is a limit in $L^2$ (or, alternatively, in probability); the limit does, in general, **not** exist in a pointwise sense. This means, in particular, that the existence of this limit does **not** imply that the function $t \mapsto H_t(\omega)$ is Riemann-integrable for each $\omega \in \Omega$.
This is really something you should be careful about when working with such limits: in which sense does the limit exist?

Let's turn to the question why we cannot introduce the Itô integral in a pointwise sense. There is the following general statement which is a direct consequence of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem (see below for a detailed proof):

> **Theorem** Let $\alpha:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a mapping. If the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $$I(f) := \int_a^b f(t) \, d\alpha(t)$$ exists for all continuous functions $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, then $\alpha$ is of bounded variation.

This means that if we define a stochastic integral with respect to a stochastic process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ in a pointwise sense

$$\int_0^t f(s) \, dX_s(\omega), \qquad \omega \in \Omega$$

as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, then this integral is only well-defined for all continuous functions if $t \mapsto X(t,\omega)$ is of bounded variation (on compacts) for all $\omega \in \Omega$. However, it is well-known that the sample paths of a Brownian motion are almost surely of unbounded variation, and therefore the definition of a stochastic integral in a pointwise sense is not a good idea: the class of functions which we can integrate would not even include the continuous functions.

---

**Proof of the above theorem:** The idea for this proof is taken from *R. Schilling & L. Partzsch: Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes*, Corollary A.41.

Consider the normed spaces $$(X,\|\cdot\|_X) := (C[a,b],\|\cdot\|_{\infty}) \qquad \text{and} \qquad (Y,\|\cdot\|_Y) := (\mathbb{R},|\cdot|).$$ For a partition $\Pi = \{a=t_0<\ldots<t_n=b\}$ of the interval $[a,b]$ define $I^{\Pi}:X \to Y$ by

$$I^{\Pi}(f) := \sum_{t_j \in \Pi} f(t_{j-1}) (\alpha(t_j)-\alpha(t_{j-1})).$$

Since, by assumption, $I^{\Pi}(f) \to I(f)$ as $|\Pi| \to 0$ for all $f \in C[a,b]$, we have

$$\sup_{\Pi} |I^{\Pi}(f)| \leq c_f < \infty$$

for all $f \in C[a,b]$. Applying the Banach Steinhaus theorem we find

$$\sup_{f \in C[a,b], \|f\|_{\infty} \leq 1} \sup_{\Pi} I^{\Pi}(f) < \infty$$

which is equivalent to

$$\sup_{\Pi} \sup_{f \in C[a,b],\|f\|_{\infty} \leq 1} |I^{\Pi}(f)| < \infty. \tag{2}$$

For a partition $\Pi$ let $f_{\Pi}:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a piecewise linear continuous function such that

$$f_{\Pi}(t_{j-1}) = \text{sgn} \, (\alpha(t_j)-\alpha(t_{j-1}))$$

for all $j=1,\ldots,n$. By the very choice of $f_{\Pi}$, we have

$$I^{\Pi}(f_{\Pi}) = \sum_{t_j \in \Pi} |\alpha(t_j)-\alpha(t_{j-1}))| \leq \sup_{f \in X, \|f\|_X \leq 1} |I^{\Pi}(f)|. \tag{3}$$

Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$, we conclude

$$\text{VAR}_1(\alpha,[a,b]) = \sup_{\Pi} I^{\Pi}(f_{\pi}) \leq \sup_{\Pi} \sup_{f \in C[a,b],\|f\|_{\infty} \leq 1} |I^{\Pi}(f)| < \infty.$$

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the application of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem?

Comment: @Dominik See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very interesting application of the Banach Steinhaus theorem.

Comment: If the brownian motions are of unbounded variation almost surely, that means the integral doesn't exist almost surely. But how can it still converge in probability?

Comment: @ZHU Why not? Convergence in probability is weaker than pointwise convergence.

Comment: Thanks for this very nice answer. One question: why does the fact that $I^\Pi(f) \to I(f)$ imply that $\sup_\Pi | I^\Pi(f) | \le c_f < \infty$?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I was a bit sloppy there; more accurately, it should read $\sup_{\text{$\Pi$ with $|\Pi|<r$}} |I^{\Pi}(f)| \leq c_f < \infty$ for some $r>0$. (The condition $|\Pi|<r$ doesn't make a difference lateron in the proof since we can always refine the partition. In fact, we could even discuss away this restriction but, as I said, it doesn't matter anyway.) Compare this with the following basic result: *If $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is such that $a=\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exists, then $\sup_{n \geq N} |a_n| <\infty$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$.*

Comment: @saz its not very obvious to me as to how the Ito integral solves the problem of lack of convergence. Nor, is it clear what the $\alpha$ in $d\alpha$ represents in the Riemann case

Comment: @Permian The lack of convergence concerns **pointwise** convergence; the sequence may, however, convergence in a weaker sense (in probability/in distribution/....). Not clear what you mean by "what the $\alpha$ represents in the Riemann case". If you want to have Riemann integral, then just take $\alpha(s)=s$; it's a particular case of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.