# Why do we need Ito's integrals?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Why do we need Ito's integrals? Why couldnt we just use Riemann integral when integrating with respect to Brownian motion?

Comment: either a stupid question or a very deep one!

Comment: And what exactly is a "Riemann integral with respect to...(Brownian motion or whatever)"? It's the former case, I'm afraid.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2055402/36150)

Comment: Thanks that's excellent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the paths of the Brownian motion cannot be differentiated with respect to time. This means that the Brownian motion has non zero quadratic variation (indeed, for $T \geq 0$, the quadratic variation $P\{[W, W](T)=T\}=1$). Informally:

$$
dW_t dW_t = dt.
$$

Consequently, when characterizing the differential of a function of a Brownian motion in terms of its Taylor expansion, one has a nonzero second degree differential associated to the double derivative of the function with respect to the Brownian motion, that is

$$
df(t, x) = f_t dt + f_{x}dx +\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}dt 
$$

where $x=W(t)$ and the term $\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}dt$ is the term that is due to the quadratic variation of the Brownian motion $W(t)$. Such is the famous Ito-Doeblin formula.
Integrating, you have the answer to your question:

$$
\begin{align}
f(T, W(T)) & = f(0, W(0)) + \int_0^T f_t(t, W(t))dt + \int_0^T f_x(t, W(t))dW(t) \\\\
& + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^T f_{xx}(t, W(t))dt.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Perfect. Thanks

Comment: @Permian Pleasure!