# Stochastic Integrals: integrator

Tags: integration, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I've just learned about integrating a formula of the form:
$$\int_{0}^t X_u\mathrm{d}W_u$$

Where the integrator $W_u$ is the brownian motion. For me, this is new territory.

I am only aware of integrating with respect to time. But now it's with respect to the brownian motion. What exactly does this mean?

I read somewhere $X_u$ represents a numerical value. Where $X:\Omega 
 \to \mathbb{R} $. With $\Omega$ representing all possible outcomes.

So more concrete, consider a game of coin tossing where you win 1\$ each time it's heads and you conversely lose 1\$ when it's not. $X_u$ could then in one instance represent 2$ (a possible outcome) after a certain time t. The probability for this event happening after time t, is taken from that Brownian motion?

So as I see it now, the formula:
$$\int_{0}^t X_u\mathrm{d}W_u$$ 
considers all those possible outcomes $X_u$ weighted with their respective probabilities taken from $W_u$ and integrates over that?

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145680/physical-meaning-of-ito-integrals